# How can I tell Stripe to calculate the tax for me during credit note creation via their API?

Tags: stripe-payments

When using Stripe's automatic tax calculation (`automatic_tax[enabled]=true`) Stripe takes care of calculating the amount of tax that is applied to an invoice. The problem I'm running into is that when [creating a "credit note"](https://stripe.com/docs/api/credit_notes/create?lang=php) **for a partial refund** via Stripe's API, the `refund_amount` must equal the credit note amount (credit note amount = refund amount + tax), but I don't know what the calculated tax refund amount should be since Stripe handles that calculation on their end.

Consider the following code that will attempt to create a credit note on an invoice in the amount of $10.00:

```
$stripe->creditNotes->create([
  'invoice' => 'in_xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'refund_amount => 1000,
]);
```

The problem is that Stripe will calculate on their end that the `refund_amount` should be $10.70 (assuming 7% tax), and will return the following error:

> The sum of credit amount, refund amount and out of band amount ($10.00) must equal the credit note amount ($10.70).

So what I'm thinking I need is an additional parameter that tells Stripe that I'm expecting them to determine what the additional amount for tax should be; something like this:

```
$stripe->creditNotes->create([
  'invoice' => 'in_xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'refund_amount => 1000,
  'automatic_tax' => [
    'enabled' => true,
  ],
]);
```

But that parameter doesn't exist [on the API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/credit_notes/create?lang=php). Does anyone have any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to first [create a "preview" credit note](https://stripe.com/docs/api/credit_notes/preview), which provides the calculated tax amounts. You can then add that tax onto the refund amount when [creating the actual credit note](https://stripe.com/docs/api/credit_notes/create):

```
// The amount to refund.
$amount = 1000; // ($10.00)

// First create a preview credit note.
$preview = $stripe->creditNotes->preview([
    'invoice' => 'in_xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'refund_amount' => $amount,
    'lines' => [
        [
            'type' => 'invoice_line_item',
            'invoice_line_item' => 'li_xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            'amount' => $amount,
        ],
    ],
]);

// Collect the tax from the preview.
$tax = 0;
foreach ($preview->tax_amounts as $taxAmount) {
    $tax += $taxAmount->amount;
}

// Add the tax onto the refund amount.
$totalAmount = $amount + $tax;

// Issue the actual credit note.
$creditNote = $stripe->creditNotes->create([
    'invoice' => 'in_xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'refund_amount' => $totalAmount,
    'lines' => [
        [
            'type' => 'invoice_line_item',
            'invoice_line_item' => 'li_xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            'amount' => $amount,
        ],
    ],
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Prior to creating your Credit Note you should [retrieve the Invoice](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/retrieve) and look at either the [total](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object#invoice_object-total) or the [tax](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object#invoice_object-tax) properties to know the assessed amount that you should use for your Credit Note.

Comment: Thanks, @bismark, but that would only work if I was refunding the full amount. If the invoice total was say $15.00 and I'm only refunding $10.00 of it then I wouldn't be able to use the tax amount on the original invoice.